# How to create custom stepper in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create this type of stepper in flutter

[image]

till now i have tried this two way

```
Widget get stepper =>
      Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: stepperLIst.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                return IntrinsicHeight(
                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                    child: Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
                            children: [
                              Image.asset(stepperLIst[position].iconName),
                              SizedBox(height: 10),
                              CustomPaint(painter: LineDashedPainter(lineColor: Colors.grey))

                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 10),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  stepperLIst[position].tittle,
                                  style: BaseStyles.textStyle.copyWith(fontFamily: BaseFonts.bold),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 10),
                                Text(
                                  stepperLIst[position].value,
                                  style: BaseStyles.textStyle,
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ]),
                  ),
                );
              }));
```

And also using stack

```
  Widget get stepper2 =>
  Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
      color: Colors.white,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: stepperLIst.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned(
                  left: 0,
                  top: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    verticalDirection: VerticalDirection.down,
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(stepperLIst[position].iconName),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      CustomPaint(painter: LineDashedPainter(lineColor: Colors.grey))

                    ],
                  ), // replace with your image
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        stepperLIst[position].tittle,
                        style: BaseStyles.textStyle.copyWith(fontFamily: BaseFonts.bold),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Text(
                        stepperLIst[position].value,
                        style: BaseStyles.textStyle,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          }));
```

Using above code I'm not getting exact output

can anybody help me to create this type of stepper

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I try to come close to your answer. I know it's too late to reply. but I am working on my issue and surfing the internet. I found your question and I get soln for that so, here it is...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomStepper extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomStepper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 5),
              height: 18,
              width: 18,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
            ),
            const Text("Title",style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 17),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 14, vertical: 5),
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                  left: BorderSide(
            color: Colors.red,
          ))),
          child: const Text('SubTitle\nAbc'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

hope this package helps: [another_stepper: ^1.0.4](https://pub.dev/packages/another_stepper)

AnotherStepper(
stepperList: stepperData,
stepperDirection: Axis.vertical,
horizontalStepperHeight: 70,
)

Answer (score 0):

I have some resources to share with you. Just check those out and see if that works out for you. These are:

- [Stepper Class Flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html): A material stepper widget that displays progress through a sequence of steps.
- [Cupertino Stepper Package for Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_stepper#:%7E:text=control%20on%20iOS.-,Stepper%20is%20a%20widget%20that%20displays%20progress%20through%20a%20sequence,to%20submit%20the%20whole%20form.)
- [Making Stepper in Flutter Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_NmzFsPgP2g)
- [Medium Article on to make stepper in Flutter](https://medium.com/flutteropen/flutter-widgets-16-stepper-485ad8d1a248)

And if you really want those staggered lines in place of a single vertical lines between the icons in the Stepper, then check out the code of the library and make your own widget like that with some minimal changes.

Comment: Thank for your efforts and suggestion i have tried using stepper widget but my requirement is show all the step

Comment: Did not get it @Goku The widget helps you to show all the steps, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I have idea ~

```
Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, top:2),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 0),
            decoration: shown
                ? const BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border(
                        left: BorderSide(
                    width: 2,
                    color: Color(0xFFDDDDDD),
                  )))
                : null,
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                child: Text(txt,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xFF1A1A1A),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontSize: 13.0,
                    ))),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 0,
            width: 50,
            child: Icon(Icons.circle, color: Color(0xFF222222), size: 16),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

Demo https://img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/O1CN01TMfTZI1MFzdk535xL_!!6000000001406-0-tps-377-254.jpg

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a late response but since I found this question unanswered, here is my solution. It is based on Flutter version 3+ but also works on Flutter 2+.

#### Method 1 - Using `Row`/`Column` Widgets

Here I use 2 `rows` inside a `column` and repeat them in a `listview`. The `VerticalDivider` widget is a straight line but you can use other methods such as `CustomPaint` or `Container` to create dotted lines or use libraries such as [flutter_dash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dash)

[Click here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=b15013ee62e5c59cc1b86b570a07c835) to see the practical solution demo on DartPad or reveal here

```html
List<Map<String, dynamic>> userInfoList = [
    {
      'icon': const Icon(Icons.info, color: Colors.orange),
      'title': 'About',
      'content':
          '\$ - American - Restuarant - Western Food\nLocally Resto with the one and only master recipe.\nIn this industry since 1988 - +1182 218 281',
    },
    {
      'icon': const Icon(Icons.web, color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
      'title': 'Website',
      'content': 'www.moscorestourant.com',
    },
    {
      'icon': const Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.pink),
      'title': 'Location',
      'content': '100 Peachtree Boston 30308',
    },
    {
      'icon': const Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.greenAccent),
      'title': 'Contact Person',
      'content': 'Jenny F.\njennyf@gmail.com\n+ 999 999 999',
    },
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Material(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: userInfoList.length,
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext content, int index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: userInfoList[index]['icon'],
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 10,
                          child: Text(
                            userInfoList[index]['title'],
                            maxLines: null,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    IntrinsicHeight(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          const Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: VerticalDivider(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              thickness: 2.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 10,
                            child: Text(
                              userInfoList[index]['content'],
                              maxLines: null,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

#### Method 2 - Using `Stepper` Widget

While the design is not exactly like yours, it is still a possible method that has a similar outcome.

1. I used the `stepIconBuilder` parameter of the `Stepper()` widget to customise the icons.
2. I used the `controlsBuilder` parameter of the `Stepper()` widget to customise the 'next' and 'back' buttons to be shrunk.

[Click here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=720d36343349aca7d9acd34e6a522aa6) to see the practical solution demo on DartPad or reveal here

```html
List<Map<String, dynamic>> userInfoList = [
    {
      'icon': const Icon(Icons.info, color: Colors.orange),
      'title': 'About',
      'content':
      '\$ - American - Restuarant - Western Food\nLocally Resto with the one and only master recipe.\nIn this industry since 1988 - +1182 218 281',
    },
    {
      'icon': const Icon(Icons.web, color: Colors.lightBlueAccent),
      'title': 'Website',
      'content': 'www.moscorestourant.com',
    },
    {
      'icon': const Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Colors.pink),
      'title': 'Location',
      'content': '100 Peachtree Boston 30308',
    },
    {
      'icon': const Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.greenAccent),
      'title': 'Contact Person',
      'content': 'Jenny F.\njennyf@gmail.com\n+ 999 999 999',
    },
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Step> stepsList = <Step>[
      Step(
        title: Text(userInfoList[0]['title']),
        subtitle: Text(userInfoList[0]['content']),
        content: Container(),
      ),
      Step(
        title: Text(userInfoList[1]['title']),
        subtitle: Text(userInfoList[1]['content']),
        content: Container(),
      ),
      Step(
        title: Text(userInfoList[2]['title']),
        subtitle: Text(userInfoList[2]['content']),
        content: Container(),
      ),
      Step(
        title: Text(userInfoList[3]['title']),
        subtitle: Text(userInfoList[3]['content']),
        content: Container(),
      ),
    ];

    return SafeArea(
      child: Material(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Stepper(
            steps: stepsList,
            connectorColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
              Colors.black,
            ),
            controlsBuilder: (BuildContext context, _) {
              return const SizedBox.shrink();
            },
            stepIconBuilder: (int step, StepState state) {
              return userInfoList[step]['icon'];
            },
            onStepTapped: (int index) {},
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

One of the main issue with this method is that the icons/steps have a background color that shares the same parameter (`connectorColor`) as the vertical lines. This means to remove the Icon background using `Colors.transparent` you would also lose the vertical lines.