# Can I remove the numbers from my Flutter Step Widget?

Tags: flutter, stepper, step

I want to remove the numbers (1, 2, 3, 4) from my Stepper and also customize the color (highlighted in dark red; current one in light red and other Steps in grey).

[Current app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rCIR.png)

Is that possible? Here is my code for the Step Widget:

```
Step(
      isActive: _currentStep >= 0,
      state: _currentStep > 0 ? StepState.complete : StepState.indexed,
      title: Text(''),
      content: Container(
        child: TextFormField(
          decoration: const InputDecoration(
            border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Enter your first name',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: You can look into [im_stepper](https://pub.dev/packages/im_stepper) , it provides easy customization of steps. If you don't wont to use library you can look into library code how it's achieved

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64611114/how-to-create-custom-stepper-in-flutter) are some options, maybe it will help you